# How to lookup for nested property?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say i have 2 collections

```
// Post collection:
{
    "_id": "post1",
    "title": "Some title"
}
```

```
// User collection:

{
    "_id": "user1",
    "posts": {
        "voted": [
            {
                 "_id": "post1",
                 "vote": 3
            },
            {
                 "_id": "post2",
                 "vote": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And i need to get this result:

```
{
    "_id": "post1",
    "title": "Some title",
    "voted": 3
}
```

How can i make a request with **aggregation**, which will display this output ?

Here what i've tried: https://mongoplayground.net/p/oeKpVHo0uRe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple option:

```
 db.post.aggregate([
 {
   $match: {
  _id: "post1"
 }
 },
 {
  $lookup: {
  from: "user",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "posts.voted._id",
  as: "Results"
 }
 },
 {
  $unwind: "$Results"
 },
 {
  $unwind: "$Results.posts.voted"
 },
 {
  $match: {
   "Results.posts.voted._id": "post1"
 }
 },
 {
  $project: {
   "voted": "$Results.posts.voted.vote",
   title: 1
 }
 }
 ])
```

explained:

1. $match the posts for post1 only
2. $join(lookup) with the users collection
3. $unwind the arrays.
4. $match only the voted for post1
5. $project the needed fields.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rOCy8nS5Gkd)